# Why declare a pointer in SDL before initializing SDL?

Tags: c++, pointers, sdl

In this code, I see that they declare a pointer before initializing SDL:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    SDL_Window *window;                    // Declare a pointer

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);              // Initialize SDL2

    // Create an application window with the following settings:
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "An SDL2 window",                  // window title
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,           // initial x position
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,           // initial y position
        640,                               // width, in pixels
        480,                               // height, in pixels
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL                  // flags - see below
);
```

(full code can be found [here](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindow#Code_Examples))

Wouldn't it be more organized to declare the pointer right before you create a window, just so it would be neater and more organized? Why declare it beforehand?

If I would take a guess, it's good to just have all the pointers in one area, so you can see all the pointers at one time. Or is it just a good habit to get used to?

The habit of declaring pointers at the beginning of `int main()`. (I've also seen this happen in other source programs, from example programs)

Comment: questions on style are off topic for stack overflow.  This is for specific technical questions.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Do what makes you happy.

Comment: Probably just for readability. I got my eyes strained when looking at: `SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow(` in one line. So many "*window*"s.

Comment: @xaxxon Do you know where I could upload questions of this type, if I would like to find the answer to my question?

Comment: @codekaizer Ahaha, I got mixed up with that as well when I first looked at the code. However if you would renamed `SDL_Window *popup` it might be a bit confusing when you would call the variable again later in the code.

Comment: maybe https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to ask a question on there next time.

Comment: It's a C-style practice, to define all local variables at the very beginning of a function. It doesn't have any meaning in C++, in fact I would discourage it when working with nested scopes, but SDL is ultimately written in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no technical reason why you need to declare a pointer before SDL_Init.  Declaring a pointer variable carries no implications with it, it just reserves space on the stack for that pointer.  It could just as easily be declared after SDL_Init, or as part of the statement that calls SDL_CreateWindow.

I honestly don't know why they put it that way in the docs.

Comment: Correct [SDL_Init](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Init?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryAPI%5Cb%29%7C%28SDLFunctionTemplate%29)

Comment: Ahhh, It was as simple as that. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Older C standards (e.g. C89) required variables to be declared at the start of code block (not necessarily a function) and SDL written in that language. Calling code don't have to, if it is written in C99 or later, or C++.

Comment: You're right.  It is a C API with compatibility in mind, after all.  I'm assuming SDL (especially SDL 1.2) compiles on a lot of platforms that only have C89 compilers.