# SDL#: Why initialize IntPtr to null?

Tags: c#, sdl-2

The few tutorials I have found for SDL# recommend initializing variables before use, like so:

```
IntPtr surface = IntPtr.Zero;
surface = SDL.SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
```

Is there any practical difference between that code and the following?

```
IntPtr surface = SDL.SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
```

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51296729/why-declare-a-pointer-in-sdl-before-initializing-sdl), in SDL C/C++ this code style is used for backwards compatibility reasons. Is the same true for SDL#?

Comment: Not all tutorials follow best practices, and I've seen quite a few that just rewrite C code as directly as possible in C#

Comment: I don't see any reason in C# to do this initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically difference exists. Here is sample:

```
void some_method()
{
    IntPtr surface2 = IntPtr.Zero;
    surface2 = MainWindow.foo();    //  Foo's signature: IntPtr foo();
    //...
}

IL code:
{
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] native int
    )

    // IntPtr surface2 = IntPtr.Zero;
    IL_0000: ldsfld native int [mscorlib]System.IntPtr::Zero
    IL_0005: stloc.0
    // surface2 = MainWindow.foo();
    IL_0006: call native int WPFTest.MainWindow::foo()
    IL_000b: stloc.0
    //  ......
} 


void some_method()
{
    IntPtr surface2 = MainWindow.foo();    //  Foo's signature: IntPtr foo();
    //...
} 

IL code:
{
    .locals init (
        [0] native int
    )

    // IntPtr surface = MainWindow.foo();
    IL_0000: call native int WPFTest.MainWindow::foo()
    IL_0005: stloc.0
}
```

Second code constains less instructions. But I don't think that you should really care about that (JIT does its job very well). In your concrete case with `IntPtr` class semantics is the same (internally `IntPtr` is always `0`). My summary - you should care about general architecture of your app instead of such micro optimizations